# Cannot install SIP using pip in Python 3.5 on Lubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, python, pip

I have a problem in `pip`. I'm trying to install Eric Python IDE, but aside from Qt, it also requires `PyQt` to be installed. `PyQt` won't work without the `SIP` license file. I have downloaded the license file, put it in the `sip` folder, but it requires the `sipconfig` module to be installed.

When I try to install `SIP` using `pip install SIP`, it returns the following error:

```
    >>> pip install SIP
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install SIP
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't know what is wrong. I have retyped install correctly more than 10 times and it returns the same error. I have also tried it on Windows, and it returns the same error, even with Python 3.6.4 installed. Probably Python has some issues.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Please run `pip` from the command line not from `python` shell and it should work. So exit from python `exit()`, then in the terminal run that command and it should install it.